# Accessing named ranges with a particular scope using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

How do I use `openpyxl` to access named ranges with a particular scope? I have an Excel workbook with several sheets, that have named ranges with the same name.

[image]

If I try to use the `get_named_range` function on the worksheet it doesn't necessarily return the correct range, and raises an exception. e.g.

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook                                                                
>>> wb = load_workbook(filename='database.xlsx')                                      
>>> wb['Residential Damages'].get_named_range('MCM')                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                       
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                    
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 480, in get_named_range     
    raise NamedRangeException(msg)                                                                       
openpyxl.exceptions.NamedRangeException: Range $B$3:$B$17 is not defined on worksheet Residential Damages
```

(What has happened in the error above, is that the range returned is for the "Non-Residential Damages" spreadsheet)

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html?highlight=get_named_range#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.get_named_range

I've written a function that can return the correct range, but it's inefficient as it involves iterating through all of the ranges in the workbook. Is there a better way to do this?

```
def get_named_range(workbook, sheet_name, range_name):
    sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
    named_ranges = wb.get_named_ranges()
    for named_range in named_ranges:
        scope_name = sheet_names[int(named_range.scope)]
        if scope_name == sheet_name:
            if range_name == named_range.name:
                return named_range
    raise KeyError('Named range not found')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is very late, but hopefully this answer can help others that are facing the same problem.

If you are looking to get the range based on a defined name which has limited scope (i.e. not global scope.) So in this example you are looking for the "MCM" range with scope "Residential Damages")

You can make use of the `get(name, scope)` method https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.html?highlight=localnames#openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedNameList.localnames

So in your problem you could do the following:

```
import openpyxl

wb = load_workbook(filename='database.xlsx')
#You would have to find the sheet ID,
sheetID = wb.sheetnames.index("Residential Damages") 
#Finally the range
rng = wb.defined_names.get('MCM', sheetid)
```

Hope this helps!